# React-Native, state doesn't change as expected due to batched update, but what do I do?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

https://snack.expo.io/@haosmark/github.com-haosmark-rn-pomodoro-app

I'm having a hard time updating a message string that's being displayed to the user. What's the best way to solve this?

Clicking start pomodoro (function on line 23) should display "wow, so much busy! Great work, keep on going!", this works fine. Then when I click the pause button it's correctly showing "freeze" (function on line 75), however then if I click resume pomodoro button, instead of "Busy busy busy! Keep on going!" the app keeps the text as "freeze", so my setState on line 80 doesn't fire in time... How do I get it to work?
I tried using componentDidUpdate(), it works, but the code looks terrible and confusing, and what if I want to add more messages? It will get so confusing.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.activeTimerType != prevState.activeTimerType) {

      if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.busyTimer && prevState.activeTimerType != timerType.paused) {
        this.setState({message:'wow, so much busy! Great work, keep on going!'})
      } if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.busyTimer && prevState.activeTimerType === timerType.paused) {
        this.setState({message: 'Busy busy busy! Keep on going!'})
      } else if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.breakTimer && prevState.activeTimerType === timerType.paused) {
        this.setState({message: 'A break after a break? Much smart, wow!'})
      }

    }
  }
```

I also saw something about component.forceUpdate() but I can't figure out how to use it. Adding it to line 83 doesn't change anything

```
togglePomodoroPause() {
    // resume timer, if pomodoro was paused
    if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.paused) {
      this.interval = setInterval(this.incrementTimer, 1000)
      console.log(this.state.activeTimerType)
      this.setState({
        activeTimerType: this.prevTimerType,
      })
      this.forceUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a callback within setState, like so:

```
this.setState({
        activeTimerType: this.prevTimerType,
      }, function() {
        if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.busyTimer) {
          this.setState({message: 'Busy busy busy! Keep on going!'})
        } else if (this.state.activeTimerType === timerType.breakTimer) {
          this.setState({message: 'A break after a break? Much smart, wow!'})
        }
      })
```